# Report Earliest Item in List

Tags: snap-lang

I am using Snap! to try to find the earliest item in a list. For instance, in list [3,1,2], I would like to report "1." I would like the solution to work for words as well (for instance, given list [Bob, George, Ari] report "Ari").

I tried to use recursion to solve the problem

[image]

and the solution works. However, I cannot find a way to do so recursively without the second "if else" statement. Is there a way to use recursion to solve this problem without the "if 0= length of..." statement?

Play with it [here](http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=mrcohen754&ProjectName=Earliest%20In).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do this without two `if...else` statements. You need two checks:

1. Is the list exhausted?
2. Is the first element less than all the following elements?

In some languages, you can use the conditional ternary operator `?:`, but I don't think Snap! supports that. It's really just syntactic sugar for an `if...else` anyway.

---

You can do some clean-up on this function, though.

1. I recommend explicitly handling the case of a zero-length list.
2. "Earliest" is confusing. I recommend the term "least", since you're checking with the "less than" operator.
3. Don't call `keep items such that [] from []` multiple times. This is inefficient and potentially a bug if someone modifies one line but forgets to modify the other. Instead, save the result in a script variable.
4. Don't compare the current first element to every element in the list. This gives the function an O(n^2) run time. Instead, compare it only to the least element so far. This reduces the run time to O(n).

Some of these changes are implemented here:

[image]